# Trying to write script to return the power of a number in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a power script (purely for training purposes I'm quite new to C++)

```
using namespace std;


double power(double x, int y)
{
    double result;
    if(y=0)
    {
        result = 1;
    }
    else if (y=1)
    {
        result = x;
    }
    else if (y>1)
    {
        result = x;
        int n = 1;
        while(n<y)
        {
            result = result*x;
            n++;
        }
    }
    cout<<result<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    power(9,3);
    return 0;
}
```

regardless of which number I set as y, it always simply returns the value of x. even if I did "power(8,0)" it would return 8 even though I specified that when y = 0 result= 1.

Can someone please explain why this isn't working?

Comment: The function does not return anything - there is no return statement. It just prints out a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
else if (y=1)
{
    result = x;
}
```

This is always true.It should be

```
else if (y==1)
{
    result = x;
}
```

You have a typo on the `if(y=0)` also.
Plus you are printing the result inside the function even though the function is non void.

Answer (score 1):

`=` is for assignment. `==` is for conditionals. You're currently assigning `y`, not checking its value, in your `if-then`.

Your IDE should have warned you about this. Code::Blocks complains to me:

> D:\Programming\C++\TempProject\main.cpp|33|warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]|

After fixing this, your code works as expected. You're still not returning a value from a function you defined to return `double`, though, so I get a warning about that as well. Try returning `result` if you need a return value.

```
double power(double x, int y)
{
    double result;
    if(y==0)
    {
        result = 1;
    }
    else if (y==1)
    {
        result = x;
    }
    else if (y>1)
    {
        result = x;
        int n = 1;
        while(n<y)
        {
            result = result*x;
            n++;
        }
    }
    //cout<<result<<"\n"; <-- generally you want to do printing elsewhere, such as main, after getting your function's results. Uncomment if you really want result printed from here.

    return result;
}
```

Comment: IDEs do not warn you. Compilers do.